# In webpack 4.1 documentation is the name polyfills a semantic convention?

Tags: javascript, webpack

In the webpack documentation

https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#loading-polyfills

scrolling to

**webpack.config.js**

the example looks like this:

```
  const path = require('path');
  const webpack = require('webpack');

  module.exports = {
    entry: {
      polyfills: './src/polyfills.js',
      index: './src/index.js'
    },
    /* more stuff */
  }
```

Does the polyfills key have to be named "polyfills" (sematic key) or can the respective key can have any name as long as it precedes the main entry file?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript object key/value pairs are unordered so it does not matter in which order you **define** them. However it matters when you **use** them. And thats why chunks option must be array. Key value is chunk name so then you define either `chunkFilename` or with chunk plugin `['pollyfills', 'index']` If you are not using chunks, you do:

```
entry: ['./src/polyfills.js', './src/index.js']
```

Comment: Because of the circumstance that Javascript object key/value pairs are unordered I was asking my question.

I might have been possible that there might have been a rule by which an entry with a key named polyfill might have been given precedence to any other key. But after further investigation, I guess that's not the case.